# Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5

Tags: apache, maven, plugins

I am new to Maven,
I want to install all the artifacts to my local maven, when i tried to run my script.Got bellow error.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or on
e of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptorfor org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Please help in resolving this issue. What do i need to do in my setting.xml, which proxy ip i need to give as my poxy is been disabled on my system.

Comment: in My setting.xml file i don't see any proxy setting. do i need to add manually

Comment: I would check the full log output...I assume you have firewall/proxy issues.